# Comparar caracteres posición por posición Java

Tags: java

Tengo que realizar un programa, el cual me pida dos cadenas(una predeterminada y otra que va a evaluar) separarlas por carácter y verificar si los caracteres de la predeterminada están dentro de la que hay que evaluar y si no me diga en que posición esta mal. Por ejemplo:

String predeterminada="**c**p**a**n**s**";

String entrada="casa";

Tendría que dar que la cadena es correcta, porque las letras predeterminadas si contienen los caracteres para formar la palabra "casa". Hasta ahora llevo esto pero no se como compararlos:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] caracteresp, caracterese;
    String predeterminada, entrada;
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Ingrese los caracteres predeterminados: ");
    predeterminada = leer.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingrese los caracteres a evaluar: ");
    entrada = leer.nextLine();
    caracteresp = predeterminada.toCharArray();
    caracterese = entrada.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < caracteresp.length; i++) {
         for (int x = 0; x < caracterese.length; x++) {

         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, es importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Answer (score 1):

Sale mejor que declares los array como String , porque una vez hecho los dos ciclos for anidados podes usar la función .charAt(i) , en los dos arreglos y que te vaya comparando, me explico : agarra la primera letra y la busca en el otro arreglo , de ahí la segunda y así, y declara afuera una variable de tipo booleano que cambie a true si están todas las letras.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
            String[] caracteresp, caracterese;
            String predeterminada, entrada;
            Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Ingrese los caracteres predeterminados: ");
            predeterminada = leer.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese los caracteres a evaluar: ");
            entrada = leer.nextLine();
            caracteresp = predeterminada;
            caracterese = entrada;
            bool retorno;
            for (int i = 0; i < caracteresp.length(); i++) {
                 for (int x = 0; x < caracterese.length(); x++) {
                      if(carateresp[i].charAt(i)==caracterese[x].charAt(i)){ //cuando entra al for toma el primer caracter y lo compara  
                                                         //con todos los caracteres del otro array
                             retorno=true;              //solo moviendo x , si en algun caso no encuentra la letra ,
                                                        // ya pone falso a retorno y hace un brake para salir del for
                       }else if (carateresp[i]!=caracterese[x]) {
                           retorno= false;
                           break;
                       }
                 }
             }
           if(retorno==true){
             System.out.print("la palabra fue encontrada");
            }
         }
```

Comment: Podrias explicarme como realizarlo pero en codigo amigo?, soy nuevo y se me dificulta un poco esto, muchas gracias por la respuesta :D

Comment: Por favor no colocar codigo como una imagen adjunta porque es mal visto por la comunidad, mejor coloca tu codigo como texto.

Comment: estuve probrando amigo , pero me decia que los margenes no se que, y le puse y aun asi no me dejaba postear el codigo , agradeceria si me puedes aclarar esto, y con gusto hago el cambio

Comment: @JavierAmaya revisate este enlace sobre [¿Cómo darle formato a mis publicaciones utilizando Markdown o HTML?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: listo , gracias

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con lo siguiente, a mi me funcionó:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String predeterminada, entrada;
        String posiciones = ""; //En esta variable concatenaremos las posiciones no encontradas 

        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingrese la cadena predeterminada: ");
        predeterminada = leer.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Ingrese la cadena a evaluar: ");
        entrada = leer.nextLine();

        for(int i=0; i<predeterminada.length(); i++){
            if(entrada.contains(Character.toString(predeterminada.charAt(i)))){
                //Se encontró el caracter
                System.out.println("Caracter "+predeterminada.charAt(i)+" encontrado dentro de la cadena a evaluar");
            }else{
                //No se encontró, concatenamos en una variable las posiciones de los caracteres no encontrados.
                posiciones += i +",";
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Las posiciones de los caracteres no encontrados son: "+posiciones);
    }
}
```

Ejemplo: Si la cadena predeterminada contiene "hola mundo" y la cadena a evaluar contiene "hola amigo", el resultado devuelto por el programa sería el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si posteriormente requieres realizar otra operación con las posiciones no encontrada de la cadena predeterminada, puedes separar cada una con el método split() y convertir cada valor a entero, claro solo si aplica para tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] caracteresp, caracterese;
    String predeterminada, entrada;
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Ingrese los caracteres predeterminados: ");
    predeterminada = leer.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingrese los caracteres a evaluar: ");
    entrada = leer.nextLine();
    caracterese = entrada.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < caracterese.length; i++) {
         CharSequence cs = new String(""+caracterese[i]);
         if (entrada.contains(cs) == false){
              //LA posición i de la cadena no está en el array primitivo
              return false;
          } 
     }
     return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar una de éstas tres opciones para obtener el resultado que buscas

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String predeterminada = "cpans";
    String entrada = "casa";
    Boolean contieneLosCaracteres = false;

    for (String entradaCaracter : entrada.split("")) {
        contieneLosCaracteres = predeterminada.contains(entradaCaracter);
        if (!contieneLosCaracteres) {
            break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Resultado 1" + contieneLosCaracteres);

    contieneLosCaracteres = false;

    for (char entradaCaracter : entrada.toCharArray()) {
        //IndexOf retorna -1 en el caso de no existir
        //Operador ternario condicion ? resultado1 : resultado2
        contieneLosCaracteres = predeterminada.indexOf(entradaCaracter) >=0 ? true : false;
        if (!contieneLosCaracteres) {
            break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Resultado 2"  + contieneLosCaracteres);

    String valorEncontrado = "";
    contieneLosCaracteres = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < entrada.toCharArray().length; i++) {
         for (int x = 0; x < predeterminada.toCharArray().length; x++) {
             if (entrada.charAt(i) == predeterminada.charAt(x)) {
                 valorEncontrado += entrada.charAt(i);
             }
         }
        contieneLosCaracteres = entrada.equals(valorEncontrado);
     }

    System.out.println("Resultado 3"  + contieneLosCaracteres);
}
```